# video_recorder compressed image

Tags: ros, compressed-image-transport, image-view, compressed

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi  all,

I am trying to get a video from a compressed Image. I saved the data from the camera in a rosbag file called _2016-09-13-02-10-12.bag.

If I do :

```
rosbag info _2016-09-13-02-10-12.bag.
```

I get:

```
path:        _2016-09-13-02-10-12.bag
version:     2.0
duration:    5:10s (310s)
start:       Sep 13 2016 02:10:13.02 (1473725413.02)
end:         Sep 13 2016 02:15:23.30 (1473725723.30)
size:        1.3 GB
messages:    5380
compression: none [1520/1520 chunks]
types:       sensor_msgs/CompressedImage [8f7a12909da2c9d3332d540a0977563f]
topics:      /camera_2/image_raw/compressed   5380 msgs    : sensor_msgs/CompressedImage
```

So, I play the rosbag by:

```
rosbag play --pause _2016-09-13-02-10-12.bag
```

I try to record the video by:

```
rosrun image_view video_recorder image:="/camera_2/image_raw" _image_transport:="compressed"  _filename:="video.avi"  _max_depth_range:="0" _fps:="30" _codec:="I420"
```

But the result is that I get:

```
[ INFO] [1474033858.402189526]: Waiting for topic /camera_2/image_raw...
```

And every 10s I have something like:

```
[ WARN] [1474037302.946135179, 1473725424.251391530]: [image_transport] Topics '/camera_2/image_raw/compressed' and '/camera_2/camera_info' do not appear to be synchronized. In the last 10s:
    Image messages received:      153
    CameraInfo messages received: 0
    Synchronized pairs:           0
```

It doesn't do anything else
If I do CTRL+C it tells me:

```
Video saved as video.avi
```

But there is no video saved.

I think the error is in the warning message.

Could you help me ?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243895/video_recorder-compressed-image/) by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2016-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the solution. It was like I thought, the video_recorder needed the camera_info topic otherwise it can't sync the stuff. So I generated a fake camera_info (with the right height,width of the image).

Basically  I needed to publish a camera_info topic.

I did it in this way:

```
rosrun topic_tools transform "/camera_2/image_raw/compressed" camera_2/camera_info sensor_msgs/CameraInfo "std_msgs.msg.Header(m.header.seq, m.header.stamp, ''), 1552, 2080, '', [0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 0, 0, sensor_msgs.msg.RegionOfInterest(0,0,0,0,False)" --import rospy std_msgs sensor_msgs
```

I hope this will help someone else who will have the same problem.

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) with karma: 115 on 2016-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1